# How to localize the result of database query in the web application

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, internationalization

maybe I will not formulate it correctly, but I am wondering if there is a way how to localize an result of the database query that is being displayed in the web application.

Currently I am localizing my web application using Java .properties files using ResourceBundle, this works perfectly with the static predefined text in the content of the web application,  is there any way how to do something similar with the query results? I am trying to translate the query results which are in English into Chinese. Thanks.

EDIT:
In JSP file, the result of my query is displayed like this:

```
<c:forEach var="current" items="${alarms}">
<tr>
    <td>${current.type}</td>
<tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Are you asking about localisation or translation. Localisation is where a set of known strings are pre-translated so that depending on the target language, the correct localised set can be selected. Are the contents of your database limited to a known set of strings?

Comment: OK, currently I am using localisation for predefined strings.And yes, the content of my database is limited to the known set of strings.

Comment: DO you think I should add those string to my properties files?

Comment: If you have a finite set of strings to localize, I would stray away from translation. That would introduce way more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the message keys in your database, then you can look up the appropriate language translation from your resource bundles for display to the user.

EDIT: If your en.properties file looks like this:

```
hello.message=Hello
```

and your fr.properties file looks like this:

```
hello.message=Bonjour
```

Then you would store in the database "hello.message" so that if it was returned from a select, you would use it to look up the correct language translation for that key.

Comment: Could you please give me some short example? I got the point, but some illustration would help. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, I am rather concerned how you would implement it in JSP page, please look at my edited question. The thing is the result of the query always varies, obviously.

Comment: That would depend on how you currently print localised messages in your JSP. Something like: <spring:message code="${current.type}"/>

Comment: My current localisation looks like this: <label for="alarm"><fmt:message key="shelter.alarm"/></label>.

Comment: It would depend on whether this fmt:message tag could take expression language in the key attribute. If so: <fmt:message key="${current.type}"/>

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a .properties file for each target locale. For example, the English localizations would be in en.properties.

You could keep your existing Strings in the database, but this is far from ideal because you would have to match the other localizations on the full English String. What I would do is define String constants and store those instead. Then in the localized .properties files, to map those constants to their localized Strings.